# Suppose that H is a subgroup of G and that h and h′ are in H. If h and h′ are conjugates in H, are they also conjugates in G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that H is a subgroup of G and that h and h′ are in H. If h and h′ are conjugates in H, are they also conjugates in G? Not sure how to prove.

I said that h, h' are conjugates of g,g' if there exists k,m belonging to H such that h= kgk^-1, h'=lg'l^-1. If h,h' belongs to H and they are conjugates in H, does that mean they are conjugates in G too? (as H is a subgroup so the members of H should also belong to G)

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

> There exists $x\in H$ with $xhx^{-1}=h'$

certainly implies

> There exists $x\in G$ with $xhx^{-1}=h'$